# jQuery get data to a div

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to show users their screen resolution in a specific div on my page. I've got it working with a button and an `alert`:

```
function getResolution() {
   alert("Your screen resolution is: " + Math.floor(screen.width * window.devicePixelRatio) + "x" + Math.floor(screen.height * window.devicePixelRatio));}
```

But I want that to just show up in a div instead of using a button and alert. What I've tried:

```
$(function(){
$('#info').show("Your screen resolution is: " + Math.floor(screen.width * window.devicePixelRatio) + "x" + Math.floor(screen.height * window.devicePixelRatio));
});
```

Comment: See the documentation for [.show()](https://api.jquery.com/show/). It doesn't do what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#info').show()
```

this code will let #info display
if you want to set content, try this:

```
$('#info').text("Your screen resolution is: " + Math.floor(screen.width * window.devicePixelRatio) + "x" + Math.floor(screen.height * window.devicePixelRatio))
```

check `#info` z-index is bigger than others